# Passbook / Wallet: How are notification warnings working

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, passbook, wallet

I am currently investigating the features of wallt/passbook and there is one thing I am struggling with:
"Notifications".

Is there any way to push messages to the lock screen in real time using passbook?
If I check several passes that I have installed (clicking the info icon), it suggests to turn on live updates & notifications.

Live updates is updating the pass itself is one feature that explains itself.

But what about the notifications?
Is this working for passbook without having an app in addition?
Is it a real push message that looks as if it is coming from an app?
I really tried RTFM but did not find a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you get a *real* push message, just like with an app.

Maybe you missed this part of the manual [Updating a Pass](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1) - the section *Devices Display Change Messages* is describing lock screen messages.

> The device compares the latest version of the pass against the version it had before to determine which fields have changed. If the value of a field has changed and the field specifies a change message, the device shows the message to inform the user about the change.

So, by pushing an update to a pass, you will trigger a lock screen message for any field that has changed its value *and* has a `changeMessage` set in `pass.json`.

The only difference between this and an App message, is that you can only set the text of the message (via the `changeMessage` entry for the value in question).  Other rich push message functions like custom alerts and actions are not available.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand that custom actions are not possible - Is it possible to supply a URL that is opened in a browser then / any other linking possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you change a backfield and add a url it will render ugly HTML on screen.  The only action possible is to click through to the front of the pass.

Comment: Would you be available for a personal chat? Might be business involved, as you seem to be a good goto company for that topic? :-)

Comment: Sure - you can get in touch through the chat widget on [our website](https://passkit.com)